# Server starts half-broken Client-GUI without any obvious reason

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I'm currently learning Java by developing a tool for creating and filling out multiple-choice-forms client-side and saving aswell as evaluating them server-side. I used a code skeleton from a RMI Tutorial for the network-part and it was working fine until just now. Both the client and the server application are in the same package but run as seperate applications. For easier developing they're both running on the same system right now, although this will change when things are done.

So let's cut to the chase with some code and what exactly goes wrong:

Server.java

```
Server() throws RemoteException {
    super();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
    }
    catch (RemoteException ex) {
        System.out.println("SERVER: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        Naming.rebind("Server", new Server()); <---
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SERVER: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch(RemoteException ex) {
        System.out.println("SERVER: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

[...] methods that are called by the client via ServerInterface
```

The <--- marks where the Client-GUI is started.

Client.java

```
private static Gui_loadSets gui_loadSets = new Gui_loadSets();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    loadGuiLoadSets();
}
```

This is where the first GUI is turned visible; the one to choose a form to load from. This GUI is loaded by starting the server EVEN IF I COMMENT THIS OUT. So the Server doesn't really load the Client-App, but instead somehow magically accesses it's GUI and showing it for no reason.

I already tried "stepping into" the line before the GUI is loaded, but I end up in an infinite loop eventually, so I really have no idea what is going an.

This is my first question here, so please forgive me if I missed out anything obvious.
Thanks for your help in advance. If you need any more code I'd be happy to supply, but most of the remaining code is all about the multiple-choice-forms.

Comment: Have you tried narrowing the problem down? As in: Remove any lines until the problem does not appear any more? If you have narrowed it down and you still don't know why something happens, you should post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I tried to undo my changes to the client before, but your comment got me thinking. I widened my search and just now found the problem was happening because of a class, the server is creating an object from, was calling a function provided by the client. So apparently this led to an instance of the client being loaded by the server.
Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Naming.rebind()` needs a URL, not just a service name. It should be

```
Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/Server", new Server());
```

But I'm puzzled by your comment on this line. The `-->` doesn't 'mark where the Client-GUI is started', it marks the line where the *remote object* is constructed, exported, and bound into the Registry. The client GUI is at the client.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear enough. The indicated line is the point after where a half-broken Client-GUI (GUI for choosing to load or create a new form) pops up, with only half it's functionality, which means it doesn't load any existing forms inside a combo-box I got there. If I use the buttons to navigate to another window and back though, it gains this functionality.
There is no call whatsoever to the Client-Application that is providing these GUIs, although the server doesn't start the GUI after commenting out the "gui_loadSets" in Client.java.
Anyhow I don't what this to happen.

Comment: @Askr I can't make head or tail of any of that, but you need to fix the Naming.rebind() argument.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your effort, I got it working now.

A very basic class the server was creating an object from was referring to a method provided by the client. So apparently this caused the problem. I must've forgotten about it, since it was in there since the beginning but somehow just now started to turn out to be a visible problem.

I'm sorry for any inconvenience my bad design has caused you. :)

Also, how do I mark this problem as solved without being frowned upon? Do people attach importance to getting the accepted-answer-button? I can't do this on comments I believe.

Comment: You can accept any answer that a) actually answers the question as stated and b) should be, in your opinion, the first stop for any future visitor having the same question. If that answer is yours, so be it. The system explicitly allows that. The only limitation is that while you can accept others' answers right away, the checkmark next to an answer of your own will only appear after 48 hours. (This is done to prevent abuse, and to give others a fair chance to post an even better answer than yours.)